# How to rotate a Bitmap image received from the camera intent

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview, photos

I want to rotate a Bitmap image received from the camera intent, using matrix.setRotate() approach. However this method seems to have been removed from the Matrix class. Is there any other methods of being able to rotate a BitMap image?

**Update:** the setRotate() has not been removed I was looking the wrong class android.opengl.Matrix instead of android.graphics.Matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`setRotate()` has not been removed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setRotate(float)), use `setRotate()`.